# How not to round values in apexchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, apexcharts

I need the graph to display the values without rounding, the same as shown in the tooltip

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

In your chart options `dataLabels` use the `formatter` to define the display value, e.g.

```js
dataLabels: {
  formatter: function(val) {
    return val.toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

Full example with demo chart taken from official docs and added custom label:

```js
var options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Marine Sprite',
    data: [44, 55, 41, 37, 22, 43, 21]
  }, {
    name: 'Striking Calf',
    data: [53, 32, 33, 52, 13, 43, 32]
  }, {
    name: 'Tank Picture',
    data: [12, 17, 11, 9, 15, 11, 20]
  }, {
    name: 'Bucket Slope',
    data: [9, 7, 5, 8, 6, 9, 4]
  }, {
    name: 'Reborn Kid',
    data: [25, 12, 19, 32, 25, 24, 10]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 350,
    stacked: true,
    stackType: '100%'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: true,
    },
  },
  stroke: {
    width: 1,
    colors: ['#fff']
  },
  title: {
    text: '100% Stacked Bar'
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014],
  },
  dataLabels: {
    formatter: function(val) {
      return val.toFixed(2);
    }
  },
  tooltip: {
    y: {
      formatter: function(val) {
        return val + "K"
      }
    }
  },
  fill: {
    opacity: 1

  },
  legend: {
    position: 'top',
    horizontalAlign: 'left',
    offsetX: 40
  }
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```